# Определение используемого User Control-а

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Есть довольно забавная проблема с WPF-скими User Control-ами. Пример дан под winPhone7, но, по-моему, в данном случае, это не важно.

Создал собственный WPF-контрол(`User Control`).

Далее, на одной из страниц происходит динамическая генерация control-ов (их несколько).
Выглядит это так:

```
/// Идет веселый цикл. В нем:


                        FolderButton button = new FolderButton();
                        button.textBoxFolder.Text = x.Name;
                        button.textBoxFolder.Name = x.Name;
                        button.Name = x.Name;
                        button.LayoutRoot.MouseLeftButtonUp += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp);
                        this.MainScreen.Items.Add(button);

// FolderButton - сам класс WPF-контрола.
// MainScreen - это ListBox на панели.
// textBoxFolder - TextBox контрола.
```

И таких control-ов несколько.

Теперь, собственно, вопросы:

1) Как можно в событии `LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`. Определить, на какой из control-ов нажали?(И это вообще возможно?). Можно ли как-то достучаться до поля Name данного контрола?

В принципе, подошло бы, например, свойство RoutedEventArgs e.OriginalSource.Text:
[image]

но оно похоже `private` и из метода его не вызвать.

2) Это вообще нормальная практика: присвоить куче динамически созданных объектов один обработчик и в нем спрашивать:"Ты Ктоаа?!"?

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто. В дебаге вы видите тип элемента `OriginalSource`, есть также `sender` объект. Определите, что Вы хотите получить и с чем работать (`sender`, по-моему, будет кнопкой `Button`, который отправил Вам событие). Для того, чтобы уточнить Ваш элемент в C# используется очень простая конструкция:

```
Button get_me_a_button = (Button)sender; // при sender == null или не том типе исключение
     //или так:
var get_me_button = sender as Button; // при sender == null или не том типе выдает тоже null
```

Также, если Вас пугает динамическое создание элемента, есть альтернативные пути (при очень больших наборах тех же кнопок, это становиться неизбежно). Одним из них является использование шаблонов `WPF control-ов`, которые работают вроде как список и привязываются к данным. В WPF можно создать `ListBox` и `ListBoxItem` так, что Вы уже их потом не узнаете, что это на самом деле `ListBox`.

Comment: Точно, сработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Так `object sender` и должен быть инициатором события.

   Кроме того, если нужно проверить нажатие у родителя, то можно воспользоваться хэлпером
    [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752). Это может понадобится, если у вас в `TextBlock` расположены еще какие-либо UI-элементы.
2. Если логика обработки события для всех этих элементов (практически) одинаковая, то да - это нормальная практика.

PS. Если вы не хотите, что бы какие-либо дочерние элементы проверялись на hit test, то выставьте им свойство [`UIElement.IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible) в `false`.